# Garbage collection of Composed Objects

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have two classes

```
Class A
{
    //constructor
}

Class B
{
    private A a;

    public B()
    {
        a = new A();
    }
}
```

Suppose I use an object of B [say `b`] in my code and after I end up using it, I set it to `null`. I know that the object of B is now available for garbage collection.

I know that after setting b to null, it will be **immediately eligible** for garbage collection? But what about the object of type A? Will it be available for garbage collection **immediately** after I set B to `null`? Or will it be **eligible** for garbage collection **after B is garbage collected**?

Theoretically, until B is garbage collected, `a` still has a reference to it? So will the SUN JVM compiler detect this immediately after setting `b = null`;

Comment: If your instance of `A` somehow escapes `b`, it's possible it lives on.

Comment: they both become eligible for collection at the same time, because they both become unreachable at the same time. the GC can collect and finalize them in any order or not at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GC is smart enough to follow paths in graphs of objects in order to check if the existing references to some object are reachable. It can even detect cycles (like, in your case, if `b` held a reference to `a` and `a` held a reference to `b`.

Answer (score 3):

Once there are no hard references to b there is no way to reach its reference to a, so both are eligible for garbage collection as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you shouldn't care. It's not reachable, and you should let the garbage collection worry about the rest. Since it becomes unreachable, it should be eligeble for collection immediately.

Comment: What if I have a problem that I suspect could be due to this? :-)

Comment: @user587465 This could arguably be a good reason since you cannot count on the GC ever running during a program execution. That is, your program could finish without a single collection cycle ever run. So unless you are dealing with Weak, Soft or Phantom references or with finalizers, the reason of your problem is very unlikely to be related to this. Still, if you can describe the problems, perhaps we could offer more ideas of where to look for the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

There are also some flags you can use when running a Java program (at least with the Sun JVM) that will give some debugging information about what goes on during garbage collection.  Try the **-verbose:gc** option.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html

Answer (score 0):

Object A will also become eligible garbage collection as soon as you set ObjectB to null (* condition is ObjectA is not referred by any other *live* object).
This condition is known as "Island of Isolation".

[Here](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-islands-of-isolation-in-garbage-collection/42) is a nice explanation of this situation. ([Here](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=Eh5NcvegzMkC&pg=PA260&lpg=PA260&dq=java%20garbage%20collection%20island%20of%20isolation&source=bl&ots=ETI6ALW0Ru&sig=6O9gVuLfwV4vAu7uVKg_um0JrQM&hl=en&ei=5TbNTZOnPMjjrAee2bS_DA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEwQ6AEwBTgK#v=onepage&q=java%20garbage%20collection%20island%20of%20isolation&f=false) is one more explanation from SCJP book)